# How to manage loooong HTML page

Tags: html

I am using Gold coin Image slider, Drop down menu, Accordion, and tool tip in single web page.  Whenever it comes to modification the page, I get confused because of the such a long code view. Is it possible that I can distribute the elements in separate pages and compile in single web page?

Comment: Are they just normal `.html` pages? or are you using PHP/ a template engine?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need to use `php`.

All files ends with *.php  and in main code  just add :

`<?php include='yourdoc.php' ?>`

Dont forget to get localserver to make work php.

Answer (score 0):

you should try to put all external resources in differents files as you can.

For example, all javascript and css sheets put in external files an the import from your html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styleError.css"> 
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="slider.js"></script>
<script src="form.js"></script>
```

Use as many external files as you need, one per topic/technology, you get an clear an ordered webpage!